# Not able to click on the one of the image in the image Slider in the homepage of flipkart by using Selenium with Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, ui-automation

Below method i am using in order to click on the 2nd image in the image slider in the home page of the flipkart but i am getting "Selenium.Timeout.Exception". Xpath which is mentioned in the below method is written for the 2nd image. If you will inspect this xpath it will always highlight the 2nd image but irrespective of this with below method i am not able to click on the 2nd image, though i have verified that element does remains in the DOM for sometime and in that moment only it should be get clicked but anyhow it is not happening.

Could anyone please help me with this.

```
  Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)
                .withTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(120))                   
                .pollingEvery(Duration.ofMillis(500))
                //.ignoring(ElementClickInterceptedException.class);
                .ignoring(TimeoutException.class);

  Boolean element = wait.until(new Function<WebDriver, Boolean>(){

      public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {

          return driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//div[@class='_3ZUwcz'])[3]//descendant::div//img[@class='_2VeolH _3I5S6S']")).isDisplayed();

      }

  });
  System.out.println("Actual Element visibility " +element);
   if(element==true) {

       driver.findElement(By.xpath((//div[@class='_3ZUwcz[3]//descendant::div//img[@class='_2VeolH_3I5S6S']")).click();

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this to click the element:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//div[@class='_3ZUwcz'])[3]//descendant::div//img[@class='_2VeolH _3I5S6S']"));
JavascriptExecutor js= (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```